# Retain Project Find Result Tab in Atom Editor

Tags: atom-editor

I'm trying to use Atom 1.8.0 for grokking code, at most a few thousand Java and XML files. When I perform a global search with **Ctrl+Shift+F** , the results appear in a tab named "Project Find Results". However, if I do another global search the new results appear in the same tab, replacing older results. I'd like Atom to open show results in a new tab every time. Is it possible?

Note: There seems to be a similar feature request [here](https://github.com/atom/find-and-replace/issues/360) but I cannot access GitHub at work.